# How to fix discrepancy between SVG and its container div

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I'm working on a Data Science dashboard project and am having trouble fine-tuning some of the container spacing. I've turned most of the page features off to reduce the scope of the problem. I'm trying to achieve 4 evenly spaced div containers in the 960x600 main container, however, the lower right div with subcontainers keeps throwing off the alignment. I'm sure there is a way to do this elegantly with HTML and CSS but coming from a background in Python I haven't been able to narrow down the root cause. Now after struggling all yesterday on it feel it's time to put up my hand and ask for help.

```
//HTML
        <div class="container shared" id="Time-Series">
            <div class="sub-container" id="random-walk">
                <h1>Random Walk</h1>
                <p id="D1-values">D1 Values</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-container" id="histogram">
                <h1>Normal vs Cauchy Sampling</h1>
                <p id="D2-values">D2 Values</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-container" id="cumulative">
                <h1>Random Accumulation</h1>
                <p id="D3-values">D3 Values</p>
            </div>
            <script src="/rand.js"></script>
        </div>

//Javascript
const randomContainer = document.getElementById('Time-Series');
const subcanvusheight = randomContainer.offsetHeight;
const subcanvuswidth = randomContainer.offsetWidth;
const thirds = subcanvusheight / 3;

function renderCanvus(containerDiv) {
    // General function to render copies of canvas
    const canvusObj = d3
        .select(containerDiv)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', '100%')
        .attr('height', `${thirds}`)
        .attr('id', 'Random-chart');
    return canvusObj;
}
```

The canvases are created in the javascript files with the D3 module. However, for whatever reason, somewhere along the rendering path, about 10px is added to the bottom of each throwing off the whole grid. I've done my best to search out that 10px in my code and chrome dev console but haven't been able to find any hint of it yet. I've also tried doing a css reset to no effect. If anyone has any suggestions about why this is happening and how to fix it that would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
//CSS
* { box-sizing: border-box }

.main-container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 600px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    border: 3px solid black;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.shared {
    display: flex;
    border: none;
    height: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.sub-container {
    border: 3px solid black;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: stretch;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `* { box-sizing: border-box }` so the widths of all elements include their border in their width. Otherwise, if you have an element with `width: 100px` and a 1px border, then the whole element is 102px wide.

Comment: Alas, `box-sizing` was already at the type of the css file. I've updated the question to reflect it's true state.

Comment: I'm unable to re-create your issue with what is provided, do you have some sampled data to render the charts? What is inside `rand.js` ?

Comment: the rand.js pings back to a node.js script that's getting random numbers in an overly complicated way but really any random coordinates will do.

Comment: The issue doesn't appear to be in what you have provided - it is likely in the canvas and what is being written there.

Comment: Thanks @sbgib even info about where else to investigate is helpful at this point. How a more experienced web dev would describe this problem is helpful.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way that you might be able to either resize the canvases or offset the canvas datum coordinates so that the charts get rendered correctly (i.e. render y=0px at y=10px).

Comment: Without having a full working example, we can only guess. If you're able to recreate exactly the problem in a snippet I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Yeah many questions with snippet these days. But the question is reproducing the exact conditions & error in snippet. I guess we'll see if d3.js is supported.

Comment: Can you perhaps set this up in JSFiddle or Codepen and share the link to the fiddle/pen in your question? If you can reproduce the issue there, we'll be able to poke about and help you.

Comment: Instead of `randomContainer.offsetHeight` shouldn't it be `randomContainer.outerHeight`?

Comment: Also your grid-gap is 10px... Try to eliminate this, for example set row gap to 0 and keep the 10px for column gap. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/row-gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display: block;` to your svg (since d3 generates it), and that tiny white space will go away. So in your function, do this:

```
function renderCanvus(containerDiv) {
    // General function to render copies of canvas
    const canvusObj = d3
        .select(containerDiv)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', '100%')
        .attr('height', `${thirds}`)
        .attr('style', 'display: block')
        .attr('id', 'Random-chart');
    return canvusObj;
}
```